# Merging Quarterly and Monthly Financial Data

Tags: r, dplyr, finance

Say I have two datasets, one that has share information at a monthly frequency and another that other information at a quarterly frequency. If I wanted to assume the same figures for the previous months in quarter - for example, I would assume that the variable of interest for Q1 would have the same figure for Jan, Feb and March - How would I accomplish this in R (preferably with dplyr commands since I am more familiar with that)?

Essentially, I want to duplicate each row of the quarterly data 2 additional times before I merge it with my monthly frequency data.

Sorry if this question is a little vague, I am very new to coding.

Thanks

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page on asking questions. In particular please provide sample input using `dput` and show expected output.

Comment: Also please only use relevant tags. Merging data has nothing to do with markdown.

Comment: Surely this has been asked before. Perhaps you should show what search strategies you have tried that have failed, so that we could help you with better ways to access SO's riches.